# Can convolution between functions on a finite group be represented as a Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: finite-groups, convolution, harmonic-analysis, sagemath, toeplitz-matrices

Let $f$ and $g$ be complex-valued functions on a finite group $G$. Left convolution by $f$ can be realized as an operator $L_f(g) = f * g$, so it follows that $L_f$ can be represented as a matrix ($f$ and $g$ can be viewed as vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ by listing the group $G = \{x_1, x_2, ... x_n\}$ and setting the ith component of the vector $f$ as $f_i = f(x_i)$). Is there any easy way of writing down this matrix? From looking online it seems that convolution with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$ between finite sequences can be represented by a Toeplitz matrix, and I'm curious if this is still true when extending to functions on arbitrary finite groups.

The reason I'm hoping that this is possible to do with Toeplitz matrices is because Sage has nice pre-built functions for constructing such matrices, and this is for a project being written in Sage.

Comment: If our group is not abelian then the dimension of the space of class functions is less than the number of group elements, so your convolution matrix is not square. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want. Toeplitz matrices need not be square, but that's a lot fo zeroes to the side. And with respect to what basis do you want to check this?

Comment: How are class functions coming into this? At least in my head the left convolution operator $L_f: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ (where the space of all functions on the group $G$ of order $n$ is identified with $\mathbb{C}^n$) should be a square matrix for any $f$. I think I must definitely be missing something here.

Comment: It's standard to do this for class functions, I've never seen it done for non-abelian groups. Without checking (I can do later if nobody else has) my total guess is that it will be true for cyclic groups, false for abelian groups but being 'block Toeplitz' in some sense, completely false for non-abelian groups. Try $S_3$, which can be done by hand quite easily. Just check it for a single pair of non-commuting elements, and the characteristic functions on those elements.

Comment: So I realized yesterday that your convolution matrix is nothing more than the left regular representation (or right, if you have to dualize because you are taking functions on the set). In which case the answer is 'yes' for finite cyclic groups, and 'no' for all other groups. If you want to see a complete answer, I can give one.